# Duplicate Parse.com User objectId to another column

Tags: ios, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I am trying to write some Cloud Code for Parse that upon creation of a new _User, it will copy that user's objectId, append it, and then put the resulting value in a new column called SubscriptionObject.  The code I have tried is:

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave(Parse.User, function(request, response) {
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey(MYMASTERKEY);  
    var theObject = Parse.User.current().id
    var newObject = 'User_' + theObject;
    request.object.set("SubscriptionObject", newObject);

    response.success();

});
```

However, the SubscriptionObject key never gets set.

Answer (score 0):

What does console.log('User_' + theObject); log?  It may not be a string.  I think it may something like "Object object"

Try using concat.

`var userString = 'User_';`

`var newObject = userString.concat(request.user.id);`

I used request.user.id because I'm not familiar with Parse.User.current().id

Unrelated, but I've never had to pass my master key into the call.  I just call Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();  Perhaps we have some differences where it is necessary.  Just looking out so you don't have to publish your master key as a global variable if it's not necessary.

Comment: The console.log returns User_objectId just like I would expect it to, it's just not setting the other column in User.